# xcrun llvm-cov show: No coverage data found

Tags: ios, code-coverage, llvm-cov

What are the possible reasons for xcrun llvm-cov show command to return error: Failed to load coverage: No such file or directory?

I have an iOS lib.
The result of the lib build is *.a binary file.
I have a scheme in the project which also contains GTest unit tests.

So I execute:

```
xcodebuild test \
-sdk iphonesimulator \
-destination "$DESTINATION" \
-derivedDataPath "$ROOT"/DerivedData \
-scheme unitTestsTarget \
-project "$ROOT"/libProject.xcodeproj \
-enableCodeCoverage YES
```

After that

```
xcrun llvm-profdata merge .../Coverage.profdata .../EA8FF09E-3BFE-42D2-BFA7-A39D69E7F688-45921.profraw -output ./merged.profdata
```

And

```
xcrun llvm-cov show -format=html -use-color=true -output-dir=./coverage-html -instr-profile ./merged.profdata -object ./DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myLib.a -ignore-filename-regex='\''.*\.h'\'''
```

And the last command gives me

```
error: ./myLib.a: Failed to load coverage: No such file or directory
```

I have 3 modules of a similar structure and one of them works fine and the other 2 give me this error.

I'd really appreciate is someone can give a hint on the possible reasons for this error and possible solutions to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same issue with my static lib that Xcode was building.

With some exploration, I noticed that passing in explicit `.o` files generated during the build seemed to work, but output was limited to just that file.

```
xcrun llvm-cov report \
    --instr-profile=Build/ProfileData/40F9DE10-F76F-46C0-A8D2-E1D427DE08A5/Coverage.profdata \
    --object Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyStaticLib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyStaticLib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/some_file.o
```

I tried to manually link all these `.o` files present in the Build folder as follows, to generate a combined object file:

```
ld -r -o CombinedObject.o \ 
    Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyStaticLib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyStaticLib.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/*.o
```

Following which, I was able to run and get the coverage report.

```
xcrun llvm-cov report \
    --instr-profile=Build/ProfileData/40F9DE10-F76F-46C0-A8D2-E1D427DE08A5/Coverage.profdata \
    CombinedObject.o
```

So essentially I had to combine the individual `.o` files to a combined object file, which then `llvm-cov` was able to process.

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant! Thanks a lot @Benzi
I was trying to figure it out for a week, but I've never even thought to build my own binary from file binaries.